# using ClassifierCompositeItemWriter, how to avoid the error message "Too many files opened"?

Tags: spring-batch

We wanted to write in many files. That's why we use a ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.

But in a linux server we have this error: "Too many files opened".

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class ConstitutionFichiersDonneesWriter extends ClassifierCompositeItemWriter<RequeteBO> implements
        Classifier<RequeteBO, ItemWriter<? super RequeteBO>>, ItemStream {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConstitutionFichiersDonneesWriter.class);

    private Map<String, FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO>> writers = new HashMap<String, FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO>>();

    // table_modif fichier
    private Map<String, RequeteBO> tableModifs = new HashMap<String, RequeteBO>();

    private ExecutionContext executionContext;

    private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate;

    private String folderOrc;

    public ConstitutionFichiersDonneesWriter() {
        setClassifier(this);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setResource(final String resource) {
        this.folderOrc = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemWriter<? super RequeteBO> classify(final RequeteBO classifiable) {
        String fileName = classifiable.getFolderName() + "/" + classifiable.getFileName();
        if (!writers.containsKey(fileName)) {
            FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO> writer = createWriter(fileName);
            writer.open(executionContext);
            writers.put(fileName, writer);

            tableModifs.put(fileName, classifiable);
        }
        return writers.get(fileName);
    }

    private FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO> createWriter(final String tableName) {
        FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO>();
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(this.folderOrc + tableName + ".sql"));
        DelimitedLineAggregator<RequeteBO> delLineAgg = new DelimitedLineAggregator<RequeteBO>();
        delLineAgg.setDelimiter(",");
        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RequeteBO> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RequeteBO>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[] { "query" });

        delLineAgg.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        writer.setLineAggregator(delLineAgg);
        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void open(final ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        this.executionContext = executionContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(final ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        for (FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO> writer : writers.values()) {
            writer.update(executionContext);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        for (FlatFileItemWriter<RequeteBO> writer : writers.values()) {
            writer.close();
        }

        Date dateCourante = new Date();
        List<Object[]> listeNamedParametersTableModif = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for (RequeteBO requeteBO : this.tableModifs.values()) {
            listeNamedParametersTableModif.add(new Object[] { dateCourante, dateCourante, requeteBO.getType(),
                    requeteBO.getFileName() + ".sql", EnumStatutModif.FICHIER_CREE.getCode(), requeteBO.getRevisionDossier(),
                    requeteBO.getDossier(), requeteBO.getFkTableFonc() });
        }
        // Pour chaque fichier, un enregistrement est créé dans la table
        // table_modif.
        LOGGER.debug("Création des enregistrements table_modif pour chaque fichier créé");
        String insertTableModif = "INSERT INTO technique.table_modif (dt_creation, dt_maj, type, nom, statut, fk_revision_dossier, dossier, fk_table_fonc) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        this.simpleJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertTableModif, listeNamedParametersTableModif);
    }
```

Can you help me please ?

Stacktrace error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.createNewFile(FileUtils.java:113) ~[opc-batch.jar:na]
at org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.setUpOutputFile(FileUtils.java:71) ~[opc-batch.jar:na]
... 63 common frames omitted
```

Comment: about how many files are we talking? also, could you please post the error message together with the stacktrace.

Comment: Here is the stacktrace: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
 at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883) ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.createNewFile(FileUtils.java:113) ~[opc-batch.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.batch.item.util.FileUtils.setUpOutputFile(FileUtils.java:71) ~[opc-batch.jar:na]
 ... 63 common frames omitted

This a linux limit (key nofile in "/etc/security/limits.conf") but i 'd prefer not to change it because several thousands of file can be opened.

Comment: Which is `RequeteBO`' source? db, file or other source?

Comment: Since you can have open that many files, I would assume, that using the standard FlatFileItemWriter together ClassifierCompositeItemWriter is not a good approach. You could write your own writer in which you manage opening and closing the needed files with every chunk. If you don't have any special requirements concernig restart that should be easy to implement. Another possibility would be to sort the content in advance, so that all entries for the same file are following each other.  As soon as you have to write in a new file, you can close the previously used one.